# QFutureWatcher how to watch multiple tasks/futures and finished() signals

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuture

I have some tasks, started with `QtConcurrent::run()`.
Tasks has `QFutureWatcher`. I know that `QFutureWatcher` can watch **only one** Future, but when I started the same tasks from UI, how can I create `QFutureWatcher*  on each task? Is it :

```
QFutureWatcher<void> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher;
watcher->setFuture(future);
QVector<QFutureWatcher<void>*> watchers;
watchers.push_back(watcher); // vector with pointers to each tasks watchers
```

or something else?
*** My trouble** is that I start each task from my code, but tasks executed with external DLL functions. And I have no API to stop the task. I can only wait for task is over and close task with release all related data, after I had received finished `QFutureWatcher` signal.

At this moment, I use two QFutureWatchers - one is watching the first runned task, another - starts if first task is not over and watching the second task with temporary watcher and **temporary slot** (code the same, I creates it just for receive another watcher signal with related data) until first task is over. And it watched the same code, but I must to duplicate it for waiting first task is over, because `QFutureWatcher` doesn't have queue with finished signals and related watcher.result()`s ..

1) Does Qt has any Queued task mechanism? or how can I catch multiple tasks futures?

2) `QtConcurrent::run` doesn't have cancel() slot. May I use map/mapped functions with one sequence item? Does mapped API has queued processing of tasks/finished signals? How I can realize that? Thx!

Comment: Maybe could fit your needs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfuturesynchronizer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You may use something like this (just code draft):

```
class MultiWatcher
  : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

signals:
  void allDone();

public:
  void run() override;
  QFutureSynchronizer _sync;
};

void MultiWatcher::run()
{
  _sync.waitForFinished();
  emit allDone();
}


class Test
  : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  //...
  void do();
  void onDone();
};

void Test::do()
{
  // fill some futures
  auto w = new MultiWatcher();
  w->_sync.addFuture( f1 ); // Not thread-safe
  w->_sync.addFuture( f2 );
  w->_sync.addFuture( f3 );
  // ...
  connect( w, &MultiWatcher::allDone, this, &Test::onDone );
  w->start();
}

void Test::onDone()
{
  sender()->deleteLater();
  qDebug() << "All futures are done";
}

//...
test->do();
```

2) There is [`QFuture::cancel()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#cancel) method for mapped calculations.It is not clear from your question, how do you get futures, so it is hard to say more. You may read about [concurrency in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) and ask more questions, if you will have some.

`QFuture::cancel` will not work with `QtConcurrent::run`, you need to design another interruption mechanism inside your thread code. For example:

```
std::atomic_bool _isRunning = true; // somewhere in code

void MyWorker::doWork()
{
  while (_isRunning)
  {
    // Do next step of computation
  }
}

// Use _isRunning = false; to interrupt. It's thread-safe.
```

But it is risky to interrupt code that you don't manage (from external .dll), because you may have a lot of leaks. That's why there is no "terminate" API in QtConcurrent.

**P.S.** Please, don't write that [I'm do it wrong with QThread](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/). There are everything good. I know what I'm doing. This is a good sample, where inheritance of `QThread` is OK.

Comment: I can't seem to get your example to compile, there are strange linking errors when I try to add #include <QFutureSynchronizer> to the MultiWatcher header file. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @ejectamenta you need to configure your project to use QtConcurrent module.

Comment: My problem was related to /clr setting on some of the moc_ files

Answer (score 1):

> Does Qt has any Queued task mechanism?

Qt provides a powerful signal&slot framework, which is perfect for such an application.

Implementation Steps:

1. Create a Worker Class (QObject derived) which has a slot `executeTask(int foo, QString bar)` that contains the task implementation.
2. Instantiate a `QThread` and move your Worker class instance to that QThread using `QObject::moveToThread`
3. Start the Thread
4. Run Tasks by either emitting a signal which is connected to `executeTask` or by calling `QMetaMethod::invoke` on the `executeTask` method.

Notes:

- Qt will queue your calls to `executeTask` (as long as you use one of the methods described in 4.) and they will be executed in order.
- To quickly termiante your Worker you could use `QThread::requestInterruption` and check for cancellation in your `executeTask` method using `QThread::isInterruptionRequested`.
- To force terminate your Worker you could use `QThread::terminate`.
- Otherwise use `QThread::quit` and `QThread::wait` to gracefully terminate the worker and wait till all Tasks have been executed.

Comment: terminate() is dangerous lethal if the thread is holding some lock.. not recommended in production code unless situation is truly dire or you know you're in a place where you know it's safe..